# Trying to convert a string into a list in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a column, which looks something like this

```
cleaned
['11-111']
['12-345', '67-789']
['00-000', '01-234']
```

into a list, since I read that Pandas initially interprets list as strings from this article:
https://towardsdatascience.com/dealing-with-list-values-in-pandas-dataframes-a177e534f173

I using the function mentioned in the article

```
master["cleaned"] = master["cleaned"].apply(eval)
```

but I am getting this error

```
eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

I tried looking them up, but I can't figure it out

Comment: What is the `dtype` of your `cleaned` column? (`master['cleaned'].dtype`) and what happens if you do: `master['cleaned'].str[0]`?

Comment: @BeRT2me idtype('O'); if I do that code, I only get [

Comment: Okay, so it is for sure a string, I go back to my comment that one of the "lists" isn't properly formatted.

Comment: What happens if you do `print(master["cleaned"].iloc[0][0]`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
df.cleaned = pd.eval(df.cleaned)
```

There doesn't appear to be a built it to deal with failures, so you can make it yourself:

```
def try_eval(x):
    try:
        return eval(x)
    except:
        return x

df.cleaned = df.cleaned.apply(try_eval)
```

Then you can look for the ones that didn't convert by doing:

```
df.cleaned[df.cleaned.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

Comment: Your original way worked for me as well though... so I think there's a different issue at hand.

Comment: I am getting an invalid syntax error

Comment: There's probably some incorrectly formatted lists further down your dataframe.

Comment: is there a way to find it efficiently? I have 180k rows to comb through

Comment: @Dynasty2468 Gave a way in my updated answer~

Comment: Found it! Turns out there was a rogue quotation mark

Comment: That would do it! Glad it wasn't a large number of issues :')